# How can I verify that CNTLM works correctly?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, terminal, proxy, cntlm

I had installed and configured CNTLM on my Windows 7 machine.

CNTLM is running and I can see it in Process. I have problems with a development tool that points to http://localhost:3128, I have doubts that CNTML doesn't work correctly.

**Question:**

How can I get a url form command line passing by CNTLM proxy?

**Version:**

```
Windows 7 
cntlm   0.92.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\var\log`. CNTLM log is there. Also it writes the same information into a Windows Application Event log.